# How to insert string containing = using batch script

Tags: string, batch-file

I have a config string.

```
CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5
```

want to insert this string from a batch file to the config file.

```
echo CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5>a.txt
```

It fails. File a.txt is empty.
I guess command line thinks CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to be variable in itself.
Tried with enclosing the line in double quotes

```
echo "CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5">a.txt
```

but then the file also contains the string with double quotes and not without it.

Also tried

```
echo CONNECTION_TIMEOUT ^= 5>a.txt
```

but no luck.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Your command says redirect file handle 5 (probably unused) to a.txt. Put a space between `5` and `>` so cmd will put in the default which is file handle 1. It will show in batch as `echo CONNECTION_TIMEOUT ^= 5 1>a.txt` if you type `echo CONNECTION_TIMEOUT ^= 5 >a.txt`

Comment: Put the redirected file at _beginning_ of the line: `>a.txt echo CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5`

Comment: Very cool little trick I wasn't aware of, @Aacini !